# Reproducir un audio MP3 mediante onClick en Next.JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, botón, audio

Tengo dudas sobre este código. El objetivo que quiero lograr es conseguir reproducir una pequeña porción de audio en mp3 (que ha sido designado en la función) cuando se haga 'click' en el botón. Alguna idea? Gracias.

```
import Head from 'next/head'

    export default function Home() {
      function play() {
        var audio = document.getElementById('a1');
        audio.play();
      }

      return (
        <div className='home'>
          <Head>
            <title>Create Next App</title>
            <link rel='icon' href='/favicon.ico' />
          </Head>
          <div className='container'>
            <div className='col'>
              <button onClick={play()}>Click</button>
              <audio id='a1' src='/static/src.mp3'></audio>
          </div>
```

Comment: y cual es el problema?

Comment: No se me reproduce... Seguiré probando de todas formas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No tienes que invocar la función con los paréntesis. Sino pasar la referencia.

Así.

```
 <button onClick={play}>Click</button>
```

Comment: Genial. Funcionó. Muchas gracias, la comunidad española de stackoverflow es genial, sois muy amables.

Comment: de nada. Graciass!!